# jQuery easy tabs plugin without transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

At the moment I am using [jQuery easy tabs](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) for some tabs I have created on my site.

how can I disable the default animated transition between each tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set in configuration animate to false

```
$("#tab-full-container").easytabs({
  animate: false
});
```